# New Excel file with OfficeOpenXml in ASP.Net MVC : nothing is returned

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, excel

## Context

I create an Excel file with [OfficeOpenXml](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), but nothing is returned to browser.

Any idea why ?

## Code

**[C#] :**

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(string[] mails)
{
    using (var ep = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Contacts");

        for (var i = 0; i < mails.Length; i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value = mails[i];
        }

        Byte[] bytes = ep.GetAsByteArray();

        return new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileDownloadName = "Contacts.xls" };
    }
}
```

**[JavaScript] :**

```
$('#contacts-excel-btn').click(function () {
    var mails = [],
        uniqueMails = [];

    $('.email-td').each(function () {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        if (txt) {
            mails.push(txt);
        }
    });

    $.each(mails, function (i, el) {
        if ($.inArray(el, uniqueMails) === -1) {
            uniqueMails.push(el);
        }
    });

    if (uniqueMails[0]) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Contact/ExportToExcel',
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            data: { mails: uniqueMails }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens when you just run your c# URL in the browser?

Comment: @LeeTaylor - `NullReferenceException` about `mails`.

Comment: ok, that's because you wouldn't have POSTed any data. I'd try and establish whether the C# is faulty OR the JS is faulty. At the moment it's hard to tell

Comment: Everything looks good until the `return`. `bytes` is filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my issue.

According to [this article](http://slodge.blogspot.fr/2012/09/downloading-dynamic-excel-files-from.html), I replaced my `return` with:

```
var butes = ep.GetAsByteArray();
var fileName = "Contacts.xlsx";

return base.File(bytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
```

And according to [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?380625-AJAX-s-XMLHttpRequest-used-to-bring-back-PDF-and-Excel-docs), I replaced my ajax approach by a html form approach:

**[JS] :**

```
$.each(uniqueMails, function (i, el) {
    $('#contacts-excel-form').append('<input type="hidden" name="mails[' + i + ']" value="' + el + '" />');
});

$('#contacts-excel-form').submit();
```

**[C#] :**

```
var mails = Request.Form.AllKeys;

for (var i = 0; i < mails.Length; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value = Request.Form[mails[i]];
}
```